# H2 delete query limit

Tags: sql, h2

I'm trying to delete records from a h2 database (version 1.0.71) but I get a query syntax error. The query I perform is:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE QUERY_FIELD LIKE '%somevalue%' LIMIT 1000;
```

The error message I get is (and which isn't very helpful to me):

```
Syntax error in SQL statement DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE QUERY_FIELD LIKE '%somevalue%' LIMIT[*] 1000;
```

The `LIMIT` part seems to be the problem, isn't this supported in h2 1.0.71?

When I perform the similar `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE QUERY_FIELD LIKE '%somevalue%' LIMIT 1000;
```

It gives me the expected results. Is the combination of `LIKE` and `LIMIT` perhaps problematic?

Comment: Delete statement will only delete a record.Instead you can use subquery.

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to a more recent version of H2? I can't find anything definitive, but seems the version you have likely does not fully support the DELETE command.

Comment: Well, tried the newest h2 version (1.3.169) but that one can't read the database format.

Comment: You need to upgrade to a more recent version of H2. The version you are using (1.0.71) is no longer supported. To upgrade, generate a SQL script (using the `SCRIPT` statement) and then execute the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `SELECT` statement in the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
DELETE
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE QUERY_FIELD LIKE '%somevalue%'
AND id_field IN (SELECT id_field
                   FROM table_name
                  WHERE QUERY_FIELD LIKE '%somevalue%'
                  LIMIT 1000)
```

Comment: Well http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#delete suggests that limit should be supported for h2 as well.

Comment: Try not to rush answers in to then later edit them. Take extra time to research facts and ensure you are constructing a helpful response.

Comment: Not such a bad suggestion but this doesn't work either: Scalar subquery contains more than one row [90053-71] 90053/90053 (Help)

Answer (score 2):

This solution should work even with older versions of H2:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE QUERY_FIELD LIKE '%somevalue%' 
AND ROWNUM() < 1000;
```

Comment: is there an option to add order by to this delete statement?

Comment: No, sorry, for that you would need the "where id_field in (select...)" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to a more recent version of H2, and then use `LIMIT` like you did.

The H2 version you are using (1.0.71) is about 5 years old and no longer supported. To upgrade, generate a SQL script (using the `SCRIPT` statement) and then execute the script.

Comment: Although, this is a fully valid suggestion, I'm bound by the production environment I work in. I have no influence on which version is used. Converting databases all the time is not an option because they tend to be large.

Comment: OK, I have added another answer (using `ROWNUM`).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELETE TOP 1000 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE QUERY_FIELD LIKE '%somevalue%';
```

Comment: When I try this I get the message: Table TOP not found. Which is strange because http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#delete suggests that both approaches should work.

Comment: Yes, this is the same resource I looked at too. I'll see if I can find anything else.